# Record a sound from the phone (not the micro) with visualizer

Tags: android, audio

i try to record the sound from the phone. My goal is to launch a mediaplayer within my app,
and my app added sounds on the mediaplayer sound (with soundpool ) . But here i can not capture
the sound mediaplayer via my app . I have a file ( " audiofile ") which is created with a size , if i remember correctly, which is a function of the length to which i push on an icon , but when i play the file , i have nothing, no sound .

I go through a visualizer because i understood that a recording by mediarecord or audiorecord only allows recording to any material only the microphone.

Thanks

```
My code:

public String fichierrecord="";
private Button auriculaire=null;
public boolean beginning=true;
public Spinner selecti;
public byte[]   mBytes=null;
public ByteArrayOutputStream buffer;
public     Visualizer v;

 @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {

super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.relalayou);
selecti=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner13);
auriculaire=(Button) findViewById(R.id.oreille);

v=new Visualizer(0);




buffer=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
v.setEnabled(false);
v.setCaptureSize(65536);
Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener c=new Visualizer.OnDataCaptureListener(){

    @Override
    public void onWaveFormDataCapture(Visualizer vv, byte[] wf, int sr){

        mBytes=  wf;

        if (wf.length>-1){

            buffer.write(wf,0,wf.length);}
    }
    @Override
    public void onFftDataCapture(Visualizer vv, byte[] wf, int sr) {
    } };
v.setDataCaptureListener(c,Visualizer.getMaxCaptureRate()/2,true,true);


    auriculaire.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg) {
        if (beginning==true){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "begin", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            v.setEnabled(true);  beginning=false;}
        else {v.setEnabled(false);
           try {
               buffer.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
            mBytes = buffer.toByteArray();
            try {
                buffer.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {

            }
            v.release();
            File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "audiofile.wav");
            FileOutputStream fos;
            try {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                fos.write(mBytes);
                fos.flush();
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "end", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
}List<String> exem=new ArrayList<String>();
    exem.add("notFile");
    exem.add("file");
    final ArrayAdapter<String> ada =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,exem);
    selecti.setAdapter(ada);
    selecti.setSelection(0);
    selectitonalite.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {


                if (selecti.getSelectedItemId()==){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Select the audio file (.mp3,.mp4,.m4a,.wav,.3gp,.ogg,.mkv,.mid,.xmf,.mxmf,.rttt1,.rtx,.ota,.imy)" +
                            "on which you want to play", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Select the audio file (.mp3,.mp4,.m4a,.wav,.3gp,.ogg,.mkv,.mid,.xmf,.mxmf,.rttt1,.rtx,.ota,.imy)" +
                            "on which you want to play", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    File mPath = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "//DIR//");

                    FileDialog fileDialog = new FileDialog(MainActivity.this, mPath);
                    fileDialog.setFileEndsWith(".mp3",".mp4",".m4a",".wav",".3gp",".ogg",".mkv",".mid",".xmf",".mxmf",".rttt1",".rtx",".ota",".imy");//,);
                    fileDialog.addFileListener(new FileDialog.FileSelectedListener() {
                        public void fileSelected(File file) {

                            File mmFichier = new File(fichierrecord);
                            if (mmFichier.exists()) {
                                MediaPlayer m= new MediaPlayer();try{m.setDataSource(fichierrecord);m.prepare();}catch(IOException e){};
                             MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), Uri.fromFile(mmFichier));
                                m.setVolume(1f,1f);
                                m.start();
                            file.toString());
                        }}
                    });
                    fileDialog.showDialog();
                }
```

Comment: `(not the micro)` ... which **micro**?

Comment: The micro**phone** presumably. Anyway, a file doesn't become [a WAV file](http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/) just because you name it `.wav`. Also, unless you already were aware of this, the `Visualizer` will give you very low-quality audio, because its purpose is just to allow capturing audio for visualization purposes. There's no way to record the undegraded system audio output (AFAIK).

Comment: Yes, i heard you can record output with something like a "different sdk" after kind of recompilation. But visualizer is a (small) possibility of slight record. I want to try at least this possibility. But my code on this topic doesn t record anything, i found it on tutorial about visualizer but it s doesn t work. I don t understand the issue of this code